# PHP code. Do no detect when a user has been registered in the database before

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this php code. I have checked in www how to detect in sql a repeated entry and show the an error when it happens.
I don't know why the entry in the sql database works well but do not detect when the user has been registered before.
Any help?

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="xxx";
$db_password="xxx";
$db_usuario="usuarios";
$db_table_usuario="registro";
$db_connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);

if (!$db_connection) {
    die('Error de conexion');
}
$subs_usuario = utf8_decode($_POST['usuario']);
$subs_password = utf8_decode($_POST['password']);
$subs_email = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);

$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_usuario." WHERE usuario = '".$subs_usuario."'", $db_connection);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0){

    header('Location: Fail.html');

} else {

    $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_usuario . '`.`'.$db_table_usuario.'` (`usuario` , `password` , `email`) VALUES ("' . $subs_usuario . '", "' . $subs_password . '", "' . $subs_email . '")';

    mysql_select_db($db_usuario, $db_connection);
    $retry_value = mysql_query($insert_value, $db_connection);

    if (!$retry_value) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    header('Location: Success.html');
}

mysql_close($db_connection);

?>
```

Comment: Any effort from our end?

Comment: A few things about your code as I'm looking on it: 1) It's succeptible to injection. Check mysql_real_escape function. 2) The mysql extention is going to be deprecated (If it hasn't yet), check mysqli.

Comment: Another thing, have you checked that the first query doesn't throw any error? Some time since I worked with mysql queries, but: `SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_usuario." WHERE` doesn't need the `` around the table?

Comment: @Desaroll: Escaping does **not** prevent injection.

Comment: Use prepared statements and/or query binding to solve your injection issue. **Note:** Only can work with mysqli and PDO

Comment: @TheBlueDog My bad, then. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, I think you're trying to perform a query without a selected database when you do this `$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$db_table_usuario' WHERE usuario = '$subs_usuario');`.

Also, `mysql` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, so use `mysqli` prepared statements instead. They are just as easy to learn and use as these `mysql` functions and they will protect you against SQL injections.

```
<?php
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_user="xxx";
    $db_password="xxx";
    $db_usuario="usuarios";
    $db_table_usuario="registro";
    $db_connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
    $my_db = mysql_select_db($db_usuario); //select database before query


    if (!$db_connection) {
        die('Error de conexion');
    }
    $subs_usuario = utf8_decode($_POST['usuario']);
    $subs_password = utf8_decode($_POST['password']);
    $subs_email = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);

    $resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$db_table_usuario' WHERE usuario = '$subs_usuario');

    if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0){

        header('Location: Fail.html');

    } else {

        $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_usuario . '`.`'.$db_table_usuario.'` (`usuario` , `password` , `email`) VALUES ("' . $subs_usuario . '", "' . $subs_password . '", "' . $subs_email . '")';

        mysql_select_db($db_usuario, $db_connection);
        $retry_value = mysql_query($insert_value, $db_connection);

        if (!$retry_value) {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        header('Location: Success.html');
    }

    mysql_close($db_connection);

?>
```

Comment: great graham! go ing to check your proposal. hugs